# How check, if button pressed twice?

Tags: python, if-statement, button, pygame

I am able to press the Enter button in Python, using Pygame.
Now, it prints "once" into the console everytime I press the button.
How can i detect if the button is pressed more than once and print "more than once"?

```
  press = False
  if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
      press = True

      print("once")
  if press == True:
      print("more than once")
```

Comment: What did you tried so far...

Comment: You can have an integer variable and increment it whenever the key is pressed, so you know how many times it has been pressed. Or, in your case, even just a boolean value initialised to `False` and set to `True` when you press the key, to determine if it has been pressed already or no.

Comment: Just added some code, but not sure how to continue.

Comment: What do you consider to be "pressed more than once"? More than once since the start of the game? More than once since X seconds? More than once since another button was pressed?

Comment: Once the whole game. Since the "game" is only there to press the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're nearly there. Just use an `if`/`else` block and set `press` to `True` after printing:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((200, 200))
run = True
press = False

while run:
  for e in pygame.event.get():
    if e.type == pygame.QUIT: 
        run = False
    if e.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if e.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
            if not press:
                print('once')
            else:
                print('more than once')
            press = True

  screen.fill((30, 30, 30))
  pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: How can I make press = False again, after the while loop is done? For example if I have multiple gaming circles in one game?